# NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. Resource URL: moz-extension://2.../contentscript.js Source Map URL: ../sourcemaps/contentscript.js.map

Tags: web3js, metamask

I get the following error message in Firefox Developer Tools Console following a *successful* sendTransaction:

> "Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch
>   resource. Resource URL: moz-extension://2e34.../contentscript.js
>   Source Map URL: ../sourcemaps/contentscript.js.map"

The callback should return the Transaction Hash and the section of code is:

```
var ContractName = ContractNameContract.at('address hash');
         console.log(ContractNameContract);



     $("#button").click(function() {
         ContractName.instigatorpay.sendTransaction({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], to:'0x4...', value: 200000000000000000, gas    :3000000}, function(error, result){

            if(!error){
                 console.log(result);
     } else {
     console.error(error);
 }
 });

     });"
```

The `console.log(ContractNameContract);` appears in the Console Log and if I type the Transaction Hash manually into `web3.eth.getTransaction(...)` I can get the details in the Console Log, it's just getting the Transaction Hash that seems to be the difficulty? I'm sure it's something very simple that I'm doing wrong but any help would be very welcome.